# Will Ubuntu One be fully open sourced?

Tags: ubuntu-one, launchpad, source-code, open-source

Currently, parts of Ubuntu One have been released, but not all the parts of the code are open source. Is there any hope for Ubuntu One to be fully open sourced?

On [this](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-one-file-syncing-code-open-sourced) blog post they say this:

> **What else is left to release?**
>
> The bulk of what’s left is the code related to the website, REST APIs,
> contacts and music streaming.

I cant find anymore blog posts about the subject of Ubuntu One.

Comment: How do we know it?

Comment: The blog post you linked was from 2015. Ubuntu One cloud storage has been discontinued for many years.

Comment: @Nmath I know that it has been discontinued.

Comment: For an authoritative answer, you would need to ask the developer (Canonical), whom we are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post is outdated. Ubuntu One was back in the days a file-sync platform, for a short period of time Canonical ran a store where you could buy music, plus a couple of other things. This was all stopped in 2014 and Ubuntu One was reduced to a single sign on (SSO) service for various platforms run by Canonical, which it is still today.

The blog post dates back to 2015, when the file sharing feature was already dead. Canonical only made some legacy code open source. The SSO code is, to my knowledge, still closed source.

A brief overview on the history of Ubuntu One can be found in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_One) about Ubuntu One.